# Make CutePDF embed grayscale images as JPEG?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, printing, print-to-pdf, cutepdf

For printing scanned graphics to PDF, I currently use [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp). According to [pdfimages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages), in the generated PDFs it embeds:

- Black and white images (1 bit) as: losslessly compressed
- Grayscale images (8 bit) as: losslessly compressed
- True color images (24 bit) as: JPEG

The result is that grayscale documents are often larger than their color counterparts.

*Is it possible to make CutePDF embed grayscale images as JPEG images?*

Ideally, there also is an option to configure compression ratio.

## Update

Following the suggestion by @Rik, I edited `%programfiles%\Acro Software\CutePDF Writer\PDFWrite.rsp`. My settings:

```
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-q
-dAutoRotatePages=/All
-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4
-dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-dMonoImageFilter=/FlateEncode
-dEncodeMonoImages=true
-dGrayImageFilter=/DCTEncode
-dEncodeGrayImages=true
-dColorImageFilter=/DCTEncode
-dEncodeColorImages=true
```

File size of my test PDF is now about half compared to before, and according to [Xara Xtreme 5.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xara_Photo_%26_Graphic_Designer), the images are now embedded a JPEG (DCTEncode), while before they were embedded with lossless compression (FlateEncode). Strangely, `pdfimages` still extracts them as `ppm` despite the `-j` switch.

I also upgraded to the latest CutePDF Writer, and to [Ghostscript 9.10](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html).

And, very important, when printing, I have to select: *print as PDF* Otherwise, I would again get the lossless encoding (I don't understand why).

Comment: Why the close votes? I am asking this as an end user of Windows XP.

Comment: Questions that require product/software recommendations are considered off-topic, see help center and especially http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software how to improve your question.

Comment: @mpy Edited. Now my question is targeted specifically at CutePDF, see also the `cutepdf` tag.

Comment: Thanks, your questions looks fine to me now, so I retracted my close vote.

Comment: You have to "*print as PDF*"? From what program do you print?

Comment: @Rik: It's Presto! PageManager 4.20.08, admittedly an old piece of software, but it does the trick, and work flow is fast.

Comment: Among all the trial prints I made yesterday, I remember there was one PDF where a small grayscale image was embedded with lossless compression while another larger image was JPEG compressed. That could be the explanation. Thanks, @Rik

Comment: I read conflicting explanations about `-dAutoFilterGrayImages=xxx` so you could try them both (`true` and `false`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help of CutePDF you can set the options in the following file:
`%Program Files%\Acro Software\CutePDF Writer\PDFWrite.rsp`

---

This is for adjusting the overall print-quality:

**How to reduce the size of output PDF file?**
You can alter the parameters used in a text file `%Program Files%\Acro Software\CutePDF Writer\PDFWrite.rsp`. The key parameters are in the line:

```
-dPDFSETTINGS=configuration
```

where configuration can be `/screen`, `/printer`, `/prepress`, `/default`. Using `/Printer` can cut size by half. You may get more info at here.

---

The problem with CutePdf is that you can't set these options for compression etc in a GUI. (e.g. with PDFCreator you can do this) You need to set it in `PDFWrite.rsp`.

In the `PDFWrite.rsp` you can set all the options you would for `Ghostscript` (which CutePDF uses for creation of the PDF). There are **a lot** of options for compression and downscaling etc. You can find the options [here](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm).

For example:

```
-dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Average 
-dGrayImageResolution=72
-dEncodeGrayImages=true
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=true
```

You need to find out what the best settings for your documents are.

Just for your reference: PDFCreator uses the following standard options. Maybe some of these options are a better fit then what CutePDF gives you (you need to try which ones): (Or you could try [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) for yourself if it does a better job). **PS. Always make sure to deselect any third-party software during install of free software (if you don't want them)**.

```
-q
-dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-sFONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-dPDFSETTINGS=/default
-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3
-dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK
-dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage
-dCompressPages=true
-dEmbedAllFonts=true
-dSubsetFonts=true
-dMaxSubsetPct=100
-dConvertCMYKImagesToRGB=false
-dEncodeColorImages=true
-dAutoFilterColorImages=true
-dEncodeGrayImages=true
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=true
-dEncodeMonoImages=true
-dMonoImageFilter=/CCITTFaxEncode
-dDownsampleMonoImages=false
-dPreserveOverprintSettings=true
-dUCRandBGInfo=/Preserve
-dUseFlateCompression=true
-dParseDSCCommentsForDocInfo=true
-dParseDSCComments=true
-dOPM=0
-dOffOptimizations=0
-dLockDistillerParams=false
-dGrayImageDepth=-1
-dASCII85EncodePages=false
-dDefaultRenderingIntent=/Default
-dTransferFunctionInfo=/Preserve
-dPreserveHalftoneInfo=false
-dDetectBlends=true
```

**Edit**:

Shouldn't you also use -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false ??

With -dAutoFilterGrayImages=true (default) it will revert back to what it finds best.

I found this note somewhere:

> (note 1) Currently, AutoFilterxxxImages doesn't examine the image to decide
>   between JPEG and LZW or Flate compression: it always uses Flate compression. 
>   If you want to force JPEG compression, use -dAutoFilterxxxImages=false.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I stayed with CutePDF Writer - see the update to my question. BTW, you have a typo: It should be `-dGrayImageDownsampleType` (which I don't use as I don't want resolution of the original images to be changed).

Comment: A added some info about `-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false` to my answer. (You didn't specify `-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false` and default this is true which i think means Ghostscript will use encoding it finds best. (even if you specify another encoding) **Do use** the print to CutePDF option because if the "print as PDF" is from Pagemanager itself it could mean that Ghostscript is not involved.

Comment: don't worry: There is no *"print as PDF"* in Presto! PageManager 4.20.08. The software is a bit primitive, only allowing export to various pixel and text formats (for those who use OCR), and to `.exe`!